# Generate PDF file from image/docx/xlsx/csv file and store into s3 rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I am working on rails 6 application in API only mode. So there is no view for this.

I am storing the uploaded files on the s3 now I want to generate the pdf of the uploaded file.
For that, I am using the s3 url of the uploaded file and tried to store that new PDF file on s3.

following is my code on controller

```
if @attachment.save
        url = @attachment&.attachment&.service_url
        template = File.open(Rails.root.join('app/views/bx_block_bulkuploading/index.html.erb'))
        pdf_string = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(:template => template,:layout => false))
        tempfile = Tempfile.new(["#{@attachment&.attachment_blob&.filename.to_s}", ".pdf"], Rails.root.join('tmp'))
        tempfile.binmode
        tempfile.write pdf_string
        tempfile.close
end
```

I am getting following error

```
*** ActionView::MissingTemplate Exception: Missing template /#<File:0x00007f236ccf4fe0> with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip, :pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

EDIT

I have tried following as well

```
url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(@attachment.attachment.attachment)
data = open("#{url}").read
@base64_encoded = Base64.encode64(data)
file = Tempfile.new(["#{@attachment&.attachment_blob&.filename.to_s.sub(/\..*/, '')}", ".pdf"], Rails.root.join('tmp'))
File.open(file, 'wb') do |f|
 f.binmode
 f.write Base64.decode64(@base64_encoded)
 f.rewind
end
```

but it's not working I got following error
"File type PNG image (image/png) is not supported"
while I open the pdf file from /tmp folder, and got a blank file

Edit

```
    pdf_string = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(template: 'bx_block_bulkuploading/index.pdf.erb', layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb', locals: {attachment: @attachment})
    pdf_string = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_string)
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(["#{@attachment&.attachment_blob&.filename.to_s.sub(/\..*/, '')}", ".pdf"], 
    Rails.root.join('tmp'))
    tempfile.binmode
    tempfile.write pdf_string
    tempfile.close
```

This code works fine with the image file like jpg/png and able to generate pdf with the image.

but how to achieve that with the windows file(docx/xlsx) or csv/text file?

I try to open those files by the following code but get the Readtimeout error for a small file.

```
    url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(@attachment.attachment.attachment)
    data = open("#{url}").read
```

Comment: Obviously you have only posted part of the code but it does not look like you are rendering anything in response to the request, which is why you are receiving this error. You could just add something simple like `render json: {status: "OK" data: "Upload Complete"}`